# populate dropdown from api in flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, api

I have an API from SQL server table with the following result:

`[["Nom1", "Prénom1"], ["Nom2", "Prenom2"]]`

where the API is `http://192.168.2.220:5000/api/get_user`

I want to display the result in a dropdown menu dynamically.

Comment: I think you can remove the python tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to create function to get the data from the API

```
List user_data = List();
String user_id;

void getUser() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.2.220:5000/api/get_user"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}); //if you have any auth key place here
    var response = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      user_data = response ;
    });
  }
```

You need to initiate it in `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.getUser();
  }
```

Then you can use it in your code by creating Dropdown Widget. I could not get what your first and second element means in your array, but logic should be like following:

```
DropdownButton(
              items: user_data.map((item) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: new Text(
                      item[
                          'field'], // names that the API dropdown contains
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    value: item['field']
                        .toString() 
                    );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  user_id = newValue;
                });
              },
              value:
                  user_id, 
            )
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but you forget that you use a Future function to get data to the server, so you need to use `.then()` to get the callback and a `setState()` or a FutureBuilder to use data getted !

Comment: It's an asynchronous function.

Comment: getUser function is declared Future<String> so you need to return some string from the function or change to void type if you're not going to return any data.

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: "operateur",
  home: MyApp(),
 ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List user_data = List();
  String user_id;

  void getUser() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.2.220:5000/api/get_user"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}); 
    var response = json.decode(res.body);

     setState(() {
      user_data = response ;
      print(user_data);
      print(user_data.runtimeType);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            DropdownButton(
                items: user_data.map((item){
                    return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: new Text(
                          item['field'],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0,),),
                          value: item['field'].toString());
                }).toList(),
                onChanged:  (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {user_id = newValue;});
                    },
                value:user_id,)
          ],) ,
        ) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this error

======== Exception caught by widgets library ==========================

The following _TypeError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#a87ca):

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).